# Converting UTC Timestamp in CSV to Local time (PST)

Tags: python, excel, time, gps

I am looking for a code on how to convert timestamps from some GPS data in a csv file to local time (in this case PST). I do have some other files I would have to convert also to CDT and EDT.

This is what the output looks like:

2019-09-18T07:07:48.000Z

I would like to create a separate column in the right of the Excel for the Date and another for the time EX:

```
TIME_UTC                    DATE          TIME_PST
2019-09-18T07:07:48.000Z    09-18-2019    12:07:48 AM
```

I only know basic Python and nothing about Excel in python so it would be super helpful!

Thank you!!!

Comment: This can easily be done with formula in Excel, is Python necessary?

Comment: Hi Scott, would you know how to do it in Excel then?

Answer (score 1):

By calling to `localize` you tell in what TZ your time is. So, in your example you say that your date is in UTC, then you call `astimezone` for UTC. FOr example:

```
utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.pstnow())
pst_tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
pst_dt = pst_tz.normalize(pst_dt.astimezone(utc_tz))
pst_dt.strftime(fmt)
```

For more example, visit [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Excel Formula:

For the date:

```
=INT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),"T"," ")-TIME(7,0,0))
```

For the Time:

```
=MOD(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),"T"," ")-TIME(7,0,0),1)
```

And format the output with the desire format: `mm-dd-yyyy` and `hh:mm:ss AM/PM` respectively.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, this is great! Thank you so much! The only problem I'm finding is that the date will get converted to the next day since it's going by UTC time and not PST. I guess I can just remember to take the first date of the first timestamp and keep it the same for all the rows.

Comment: No, the date should be changing if the UTC date/Time is less than 7 AM.

Comment: Hi Scott,  I see, you're right you calculated that.Just wanted to see if you could help with one more thing. I see you did 7 for the timezone which is great, but how would I do an IF statement where if the date was between 3/10/2019 and 11/3/2019 it would be 7 timezone and if not, 8?

Comment: new questions get new posts.